# Pass response of AJAX only to current div among an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, ajax

I've managed to make simple voting system with single current score. Everything is fine but the problem is that when I click on a button to vote **for this particular** content - all scores in other divs change as well!! I need AJAX to output the answer on success only on current div (video votting) not all of them on my page! I think its because of this:

```
success: function(html) {
    $('.this').html(html);
}
```

That's because I have an array of blocks on my page:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="box1">
        <a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="up">
            <img class='image'src="img/thumbsup.png">
        </a> 
        <span class='this'><?php echo $total_score; ?></span> 
        <a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="down">
            <img class='image' src="img/icon-down.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class='box2' ><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
</div>
```

And span with class 'this', when on success AJAX adds response to all of them, but I need to identify them and add response only to current one (spans with class 'this', which are basically the scores of current voting), so that when user votes - only current score changes. not all of them! (if all of them have spans with class 'this' to which I pass response from AJAX. Making a specific class for each block(div) is nonsense, because I make a page that displays videos from database - any number!
here is ajax and jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".vote").click(function() 
{  
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var acdc = $('#ab').attr('class');
var potato = 'potato';
var parent = $(this);
if(name=='up')
{ 
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "up_vote.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){

$('.this').html(html);
}}); 
}
else
{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="img/icon-down.png" align="absmiddle"     style="height: 10px;width:10px;">');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "down_vote.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){ 
$('.this').html(html);
}}); 
}
return false;
});

});
 </script>
```

So, how can I make that?(change only current score) Thanks a lot! In advance.

Comment: I would suggest you use something other than an class named `this` such as `<span class='score'>` and give someone who maintains it an easier time.

Comment: @Donalda I have answered, you need to get the parent of the anchor tag on which user clicked and then find inside that parent div your desired class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use $(this) inside success function as it will changes with context in which $(this) is called, you have to store the it in a var and then use it like  below in your ajax success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".vote").click(function ()
        {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var dataString = 'id=' + id;
            var acdc = $('#ab').attr('class');
            var potato = 'potato';
            var parent = $(this);

            if (name == 'up')
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "up_vote.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        parent.parent().find('.this').html(html);
                    }});
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="img/icon-down.png" align="absmiddle"     style="height: 10px;width:10px;">');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "down_vote.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {                        
                        parent.parent().find('.this').html(html);
                    }});
            }
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: here - it still doesnt work/ it doesnt do anything - 
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "up_vote.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html){

   $(this).parent().find('.this').html(html);
}}); 
}

Comment: here is my html with .this class    ---- <span class='number-vote this'>
                             <?php
                             
                             echo $row['votev'];

                             ?></span>

Comment: @DonaldaDonalda try using firefox firebug console and then console.log($(this).parent() ); It should print "<div class="box1">"
If it doesn't then let me know what it prints, when you hover on the printed text in console you can see where it points in browser as it will highlight the element on your page.

Comment: should i write that somewhere in my php file or in firebug console?

Comment: in your php file like this :
success: function(html) {  
     console.log($(this).parent() );
    //travel up till the container of the clicked anchor tag and then find in that container your ".this" class and change its html
    $(this).parent().find('.this').html(html);
}

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the code, but presumably the AJAX request is fired on click of a `.vote` element. If this is the case you can store a reference to the element which raised the event, then use DOM traversal to find the sibling `.this` and change it's HTML. Something like this:

```
$('.vote').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $vote = $(this); // store the element which raised the event here
    $.ajax({
        url: 'foo.php',
        success: function(html) {
            $vote.siblings('.this').html(html); // use siblings() to find .this to change
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: here is the code - it doesnt work 
$(".vote").click(function() 
{  
var $vote = $(this);
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var acdc = $('#ab').attr('class');
var potato = 'potato';
var parent = $(this);
if(name=='up')
{ 
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "up_vote.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html){

     $vote.siblings('.this').html(html);
}}); 
}
else

Comment: Have you checked in the console to make sure that the AJAX request is working?