# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined - AJAX post answer only in spesific div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined

What I'm trying to create is a voting system for each video on my page from a database. I've managed to make it with AJAX the only problem is that I can't output the answer in the correct div class 'this' because it gets posted in each div with the class - so in under every video.

I need a working solution to identify the parent div the user clicked vote button on and change only its own child bot others.

Please help. Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(function() {

    $(".vote").click(function() {  

        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var acdc = $('#ab').attr('class');
        var potato = 'potato';
        var parent = $(this);
        if(name=='up')
        { 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "up_vote.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) { acdc.html(html);
                                        }}); 
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="img/icon-down.png" align="absmiddle"     style="height: 10px;width:10px;">');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "down_vote.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){ 
                    parent.parent().find('.this').html(html);
                }}); 
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

here is html with video posts and div class'this' where my AJAX answer should be posted - but only in current one - as php script adds one vote to only the video with the spesific id, not all!

```
 <div class='botto'>
  <div class='icon-wrap'>
   <form action="blossom.php" method="post"><?php $id =  $row["idv"]; ?>
   <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['idv']; ?>" />
   <div cass='homesick'>
    <button type='submit'name='up' style="background-color:transparent; border-color:transparent;outline: none; " class='icon vote' name="up"><img src='img/thumbsup.png' alt='up' name='up' class='icon vote icon-up' id="<?php echo $row['idv']; ?>" ></button> 
         <span class='number-vote this'>
         <?php

         echo $row['votev'];

         ?></span>
    <button type='submit' name='down' style="background-color:transparent; border-color:transparent;outline: none; " class="vote" name="down"><img src='img/icon-down.png' alt='down' class='icon icon-down vote' id="<?php echo $row['idv']; ?>"></button> 
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and your earlier question, which you [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358422/pass-response-of-ajax-only-to-current-div-among-an-array)?

Comment: There's no `id='ab'` in your HTML, what is `$("#ab").attr('class')` supposed to return?

Comment: video.php:576 Uncaught TypeError: acdc.html is not a function here what that says - i added >>>><span class='number-vote this' id='<?php echo $row['idv']; ?>'>
                             <?php
                              
                             echo $row['votev'];

                             ?></span> and >>>var acdc = $('.number-vote').attr('id');

Comment: no difference. im stuck on the issue. looking for help. thats all.

Answer (score 2):

`var acdc = $('#ab').attr('class')` attempts to retrieve the string value of the attribute `class`, which in this case is resolving to `undefined`.

If you'd like to use the jQuery [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method, you should do it on a DOM node, such as:

```
var acdcElement = $('#ab');
var html = acdcElement.html();
```

Comment: same error here - 
$(".vote").click(function() 
{  

var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var acdc = $('#ab').attr('class');
var acdcElement = $('#ab');
var html = acdcElement.html();
var potato = 'potato';
var parent = $(this);
if(name=='up')
{ 
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "up_vote.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
    

    success: function(html) { acdc.html(html);
}}); 
}
else