# Managing multiple comments boxes 'set' on single page - differentiate them and treat correctely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, comments, this

I have multiple comment boxes of the content on the same page and I'm having troubles identifying them to treat them correctly - for example, it doesn't matter where I try to post my comment (from which comment box) - it always gets posted to first comment box on a page or I'm fighting with input to get cleared after I post my comment but input cleans only on the same first comment box. Here what I have:
(AJAX)

```
    $(function() {
     $(".comm").click(function() {
    var parentDiv = $(this).parent('.post_comment').next().children(":first");  
    var comment = $(this).parent('.post_comment').find('.comment').val();
     var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
     var idv = $(this).parent('.post_comment').find("#idv").val();
    var posthere =            $(this).parent().siblings('.wrap_comment').find('#wrap').attr('class');

   alert(idv);
  if(comment=='')
  {
    alert("Enter some text..");
     $("#content").focus();
      }
   else
        {
      $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "river_flow.php",
  data: 
  {  username: $("#username").val(),
     idv: $(this).parent('.post_comment').find(".idv").val(),
     comment: $(this).parent('.post_comment').find('.comment').val()},

    cache: false, 
   success: function(data){    
    $('#show').after(data);
    $(this).find('.comment').css('background-color','red');

   $("#content").focus();
    }})   
    return false;
        }})})
```

(HTML)

```
<div class='com'><button class='click_and_comment'>Give it a comment</button>

              <div class='post_comment'>
              <img class='end' src="img/end.png" alt='close'/>
                   <input type="hidden" id="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>" name='username'/>
                   <input type="hidden"class='idv' id="idv" value="<?php echo $row['idv']; ?>" name='idv'/>
                   <textarea type='text' class="input_comment comment"   placeholder='What do you think?' name='comment' id='comment' ></textarea>
                   <input type='submit' name='comment_submit' class="comment_submit comm" id='comm'/>

              </div>


                 <div class='wrap_comment' id="<?php echo $row['idv']; ?>" >


                 <div id="show" align="left" class="<?php echo $row['idv']; ?>" ></div>
                    <?php
                    $idvc = $row['idv'];

                    $query = " SELECT * FROM comments WHERE idvc= '$idvc' ORDER BY datec DESC;";

                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                    while ($bow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo "<div class='each_comment' id='<?php echo $bow[idvc];?>' >".$bow['commentc']."</div> ";}

                    ?>
                 </div>
```

So, to form my problem in a question: how can I post users comments respectively to where they 'need' to be posted and how do I clean only 'current' or 'this' input - not always first. Again - everything works just perfect, the problem is that there are always more then one comment box and I need to differentiate them and treat accordinally to them. Here are my guesses that doesn't work(on contradiction I wouldn't be here) and, please, exmplain, why they don't work, coz even simple:

```
$(this).find('#comment').value = '';
```

doesn't work! maybe it doesn't 'see' this attribute. But why?! So. here are my guesses:

```
 $(this).parent('.post_comment').siblings('.wrap_comment').find('#show').after(data);
```

(that is for comment post and this is my guess for input clearing:)

```
$(this).parent('.post_comment').find('#comment').val('');
```

I found something like:

$('#comment').removeAttr('value');

doesnt work ither - am not speaking about pure dead confusion I get when this stuff doesnt work:

```
$(this).find('.comment').css('background-color','red');
```

Whoof. So, I hope someone can clear this all up a bit for me. Im newbie being honest. Thanx!

Comment: ok. can you give me the link, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358422/pass-response-of-ajax-only-to-current-div-among-an-array

Comment: Thank you let me check what I can do to help here

Comment: there you go! help me please with this issue

Comment: I m not able to find where you exactly having problem, is it a certain line in your jquery code?

Comment: $('#show').after(data);
document.getElementById('comment').value='';  here. it posts incorrectly. not dynamically to the div with comments that user chosen to post but always to first one. have any ideas?

Comment: Yep, I think you are posting ajax request when user comments. How user comments , is it a submit button or onblur event on comment input?

Comment: if your ajax is fired by onblur(when user click elsewhere after entering comment) then you can use $(this) to know which commentbox was entered and then store this value in a variable and then accordingly respond in your ajax

Comment: Ive edited it! check it out.

Comment: Posted answer pls check, I have not seen any other comment box except one inside your main div with class = "com"

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script and replace your relevant script with this code. I didn't find multiple comment box inside your div with class="com" so I assumed it is only present inside this div and not anywhere else :

```
$(function() {
        $(".com").click(function() {

            //##############################$(this) here refers to div with class="com" as this is the element on which click event has happened#####################
            var myThis = $(this);
            //var parentDiv = $(this).parent('.post_comment').next().children(":first");  

            //since div with class="post_comment" is inside div with class="com" so it is child to that div and not parent
            var parentDiv = $(this).find('.post_comment').next().children(":first"); 

            //var comment = $(this).parent('.post_comment').find('.comment').val();
            var comment = $(this).find('.post_comment .comment').val();//find element with class="comment" whose parent is div with class="post_comment"

            var name = document.getElementById("username").value;

            //var idv = $(this).parent('.post_comment').find("#idv").val();
            var idv = $(this).find(".post_comment #idv").val();//find element with id="idv" whose parent is div with class="post_comment"

            //####Not sure what is the use of below statement
            var posthere = $(this).find('.wrap_comment #wrap').prop('class');

            alert(idv);
            if (comment == '')
            {
                alert("Enter some text..");
                $("#content").focus();
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "river_flow.php",
                    data: {username: $("#username").val(),
                                idv: idv,
                                comment: comment 
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#show').after(data);
                        //### $(this) here will not point to your div with class="com" as it is in different context inside your ajax success function
                        //##$(this).find('.comment').css('background-color', 'red');
                        myThis.find('.comment').css('background-color', 'red');

                        $("#content").focus();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```